# Just the executor, or executor and witnesses to open a safe deposit box of the deceased?

Tags: wills, probate, inheritance

The court assigns a family member or friend of the deceased to be executor  so that a safe deposit box can be accessed.

What are the laws and court considerations that govern when/whether another person or persons are to witness the executor opening the safe box and inventorying the contents?

Note: Assume that the court did not appoint a wholly independent party to be the executor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### An executor is a trustee

They have a fiduciary duty to act in the best interest of the beneficiaries. How they choose to discharge that obligation is up to them. They are certainly not required to have witnesses to their activities but if there is a lack of trust in the trust a prudent executor may want a witness for their own protection.